# How to check the array length, if I have 'perPage = 20' in the 'url' address (gets 20) and there are 1000 elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

In `params` I have:

```
const params = {
      expand: 'project',
      'per-page': 20
    }
```

Gets 20 items per page.

If I removed the `'per-page': 20` I would get 2000-3000 items. I don't want to accumulate so much in a blackboard. Is there any way to determine the length of the elements that are 2000-3000 without downloading them. I need all the elements to specify `totalItemsCount` in pagination. Is there any way to determine this length, the elements are 2000-3000, not 20?

```
this.state = {
  todos: []
}



  getTodos = (id) => {

    const params = {
      expand: 'project',
      'per-page': 20,
    }
    axios({
      url: `/api/v1/project/todos`,
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => { 
      this.setState({
        todos: res.data
      });


    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    }) 
  }


  <Pagination
    itemsCountPerPage={20}
    totalItemsCount={this.state.todos.length}
  />
```

Comment: You can return the count in the response of your request to the backend.

Comment: You are not using `params` in your axios request, which means it always sends all the items. You need to add like a `start` and `count` parameter to the backend api so you can request a single page, and return not just the array but an object containing the array and the total count.

Comment: Your api needs to return it in the `res.data` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a method on your server side that returns the total amout of todos.
For instance accessible throught `/api/v1/project/todos/count`

Or to change the response of your server to be an object containing the total amout and an array of the 20 selected todos :
`{ length: 3000, todos: [first, second, ..., twentieth] }`

Otherwise your client side has no means to know of much todos there is.